# Array is empty even elements has been pushed

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to print "comments" elements in console with foreach, but when I push some elements in the array this elements are only visible for first foreach where I pushed them, outside this "comments" array is still empty. How can I solve this problem?

```
const Post = require('../models/post');
const Comment = require('../models/comment');

getpost: async (req, res, next) => {
    const { post_id } = req.params;
    const post = await Post.findById(post_id);
    const comments_id = post._comment;
    var comments = [];

    comments_id.forEach(async id => {
        comments.push(await Comment.findById(id));
        console.log(comments) // The output are elements which exist in Comment model
    });

    console.log(comments); // The output is []

    comments.forEach(comment => {
        console.log(comment);
    });
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha). The above clearly *won't* do what's described. Either you won't see anything from the `console.log` that's inside the `forEach`, or you will see contents in `comments` after the `forEach`.

Comment: What is `Comment.findById`? Specifically, is it asynchronous? (Not that it really matters for what you asked [but does matter for doing what you're trying to do], you'd still have entries in `comments`, they'd just be either `undefined` or promises or...)

Comment: This is my code                                                                                                       getpost: async (req, res, next) => {
    const { post_id } = req.params;
    
    const post = await Post.findById(post_id);

    const comments_id = post._comment;
    var comments = [];

    comments_id.forEach( async id => {
      comments.push(await Comment.findById(id));
      
    });

    comments.forEach( comment => {
      console.log(comment);
    });

Comment: @codR "*Please update your question*" does not mean "*paste unformatted code in a comment*".

Comment: To improve the question, please use the "edit" link under the question (and please do give that [mcve] link a good read).

Comment: Should that empty console log `console.log(comment)` perhaps be `console.log(comments)` i.e. plural

Comment: I've just made mistake in typing and it does not matter. Result is same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to output a result synchronously which is only assigned asynchronously:

```
comments_id.forEach( async id => {
  comments.push(await Comment.findById(id));
  console.log(comments) // The output are elements which really exist in 
                        // Comment model
});
```

When the above code meets the `await`, execution proceeds immediately with the next `forEach` callback, ...etc, etc. All these callback functions return (a promise) when they meet `await`. But none will have received the comment yet. And so the execution proceeds to what follows the whole `forEach` block... which is where you try to output the array, ... which is still empty.

To make it work, use `Promise.all` instead of the above code block:

```
comments = await Promise.all(comments_id.map( id => Comment.findById(id) ));
```